# How to insert text into an Ace Editor instance as a comment

Tags: comments, ace-editor

I am building a website where I want to allow people to code in almost any language that the Ace editor supports. Right now I have it redirect if they try to load a language that either isn't supported by Ace, or that I didn't list in my supported languages. I only have a few languages that I allow to run (because I haven't got others to work or don't know how to), and for all those other languages that aren't run-supported, I want to load the Ace editor with a note saying that the language they loaded isn't supported for running, but I want it to be a comment in that language.

I tried inserting the text using `editor.setValue([message], -1)`. Then set the focus on the editor using `editor.focus()`. Then I select all the text with `editor.selectAll()`. And then use the `editor.toggleCommentLines()` to make it a comment. For some reason this doesn't work, and I am not sure why.

I know that I could just look up how to write comment in each of the languages that I am allowing, and then convert the message into a comment before inserting it into the editor, but I want an easier way if possible.

Is there an easier way to do it? Or should I just do what I said that I could?

---

Since I answered my own question, I want to ask another to see if anyone has the answer for this:
When in the Ace editor you can press `CTRL`+`/` to toggle line comments. But if you press `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`/` it will toggle multiline comments. I don't see a function for this in the [Ace editor documentation](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor) but because it works with a keyboard shortcut, there must be a way to do it programmatically, right?
If someone could figure this out, that would be great!

[a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743328/a-user) found it! See his comment to see the answer to this part.

Comment: there is editor.toggleBlockComment method https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/commands/default_commands.js#L549 which can be found from commands

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I wonder why they do not include that in the documentation for the editor methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying a few more things, and one of them was doing a `setTimeout` on the `editor.toggleCommentLines()`, and that worked. The timeout worked best if I used 150ms or higher (I started with 2000 just to see if it worked at all, and then slowly moved down).

So the following code works to automatically insert a message and comment it out:

```js
const editor = ace.edit([element]);
      editor.setValue([message], 0); // You can also leave the second parameter blank, 0 is the default which automatically selects all.
setTimeout(() => {
    editor.toggleCommentLines();
}, 150); // 150ms or more works best
```

You may also notice that this method clears out 2 methods that I was previously using. There are two reasons for this:

1. When using 0 instead of -1 for the second parameter of `editor.setValue()` it selects all the text.
2. Because we are using the `editor` variable, the editor doesn't need to be in "focus".